# Attempting to click element by ID returns undefined error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm pretty new to coding of any type, but I am trying to click a button in the dev console in Chrome using

`document.getElementById('pd-vote-button9652052').click()`;

When I use other elements such as `'PDI_answer9652052'` it works, but for this element I am getting an undefined error.

I have looked all over but I can't seem to find an answer that will work.

Comment: is there any element on the page with an ID of `pd-vote-button9652052` ?

Comment: Can you provide some more code, full html and css

Comment: @Web Dev Guy The full HTML is too long to fit in the question box

Comment: @hackerrdave Yes one button had that ID

Comment: @NubeCoder post the html for the click element which is giving you trouble

Comment: @Web Dev Guy <a id="pd-vote-button9652052" class="pds-vote-button"><span>Vote</span></a>

Answer (score 0):

This is because your DOM isn't loaded completely and hence it cannot find all the ID's

make sure you write your entire Javascript code like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

//your javascript code here

}
```

`$( document ).ready()`  will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Thus you will be able to find all your ID's .
For more info click [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: It isn't my HTML, I am just using the console in chrome to try and force a click event on a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
document.getElementById("pd-vote-button9652052").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("hello world");
});
```

works for me in code pen with no error http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLjXYB

Comment: No bueno :/ still just says undefined. This was new in the console though "Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."